# Redirect .png image to another .png image through .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm a newbie when it comes to .htaccess

I have a few images that need to be redirected.

Example:

```
assets/images/image1.png
```

to be redirected to

```
assets/images/image1_v2.png
```

So when you visit it directly:

```
https://www.example.com/assets/images/image1.png
```

It gets redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/assets/images/image1_v2.png
```

Note: `image1.png` and `image1_v2.png` are two different images and I'm only looking into redirecting it when it's accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

By "accessed directly", I assume you mean when the user types the URL directly in the browsers address bar? In which case there is no HTTP `Referer` header sent.

At the top of the root `.htaccess` file you can do something like the following to *externally "redirect"* the user to the new image URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^assets/images/image1\.png$ /assets/images/image1_v2.png [R,L]
```

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

Or, to save repetition, you can change the `RewriteRule` directive to:

```
RewriteRule ^(assets/images/image1)\.png$ /$1_v2.png [R,L]
```

The `$1` backreference saves repetition by capturing the "assets/images/image1" part from the requested URL-path and using this in the *substitution* string.

Note that users (through their browser) can control the `Referer` header that is sent as part of the request, so it's possible that a user could make it look like a "direct request" when it's not.

Comment: Hi MrWhite. Thanks for your answer. This worked on my localhost, but not when I apply it live on my website. Do I need to change something on my server?

Also, I'm looking into redirecting specific images that could have different file names, so repetitions might not work for me. An example would be redirecting `image2.png` to `this-image.png`. I'm planning to redirect 4 images.

Comment: Do you have other directives on your "live site"? Do you get any errors? The order of the directives can be important. "redirecting specific images" - that is what the first example is for.

Comment: "Do I need to change something on my server?" - I'm assuming you already have `.htaccess` overrides enabled? And mod_rewrite is loaded on the server?